# Magento 2 shipping address gets blank while adding new billing address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address, place-order

Magento 2 shipping address gets blank while adding new billing address 
When we add info to fields in the new billing address , the shipping address section gets automatically reload and it gets blank. check here -https://prnt.sc/rqlvjg

Comment: please check in console if you are getting any error

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the older version of **Magento 2.3**

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22112

Just update the file `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/js/view/billing-address.js` with the latest version of Magento and add `billing-address-postcode-validator.js` file too.